# Cloud ML Training job failing to find matching files

Tags: google-cloud-ml

My training job is failing with an error saying:
NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://my_file_name/train/model.ckpt-2-?????-of-00001 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_29 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_29/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_29/shape_and_slices)]] Caused by op u'save/RestoreV2_29', defined at ...

I checked Google Cloud Storage and that file (gs://my_file_name/train/model.ckpt-2*) does exist.  Why is it failing to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to a single region Google Cloud Storage bucket.

The Tensorflow restore function is attempting to the list the files in your Google Cloud Storage bucket which were just written.  However, Google Cloud Storage is not strongly consistent when listing files if you are writing to a multi-region bucket.  Single-region buckets are strongly consistent in this case and won't have this issue.  They will also give higher performance assuming the single region is the same region you are training in.

See also:

https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up#setting_up_your_cloud_storage_bucket
https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/concepts/environment-overview#cloud_storage_buckets